# Google Apps Script - Connect to MySQL DB with ssh

Tags: mysql, google-apps-script, ssh

I am trying to connect to a MySQL database with google apps script to retrieve some data.
Here is the DB documentation
https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/AccessingMySQLFromOutsidePythonAnywhere/

I can successfully connect with MySQL Workbench or Python but I cannot find the proper way to do it in google apps script (which is what I really need)

I can only find examples/documentation to connect using Jdbc but without SSH tunnel.
for SSH I have hostname, username and password
The DB can be accessed from any IP so this is not an issue.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: FWIW, I used `var url = "jdbc:mysql://"+host+":"+port+"/"+databaseName;` then `var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(url, userName, password);` then `var stmt = conn.createStatement();`. "host", "port", databaseName", "userName" and "password" were all variables based on spreadsheet `getValue`/values.

Comment: Thank you for your response. This is the way to do it on a direct connection. 
I'm struggling with the SSH part as this is imposed by the DB provider and I cannot turn it off

Answer (score 1):

This would be tricky because Apps Script and JDBC do not support SSH in any way. You cannot set the SSH tunnel on Apps Script, so you would probably need some kind of VM or server in the middle which would act as the tunnel, and Apps Script would connect to the middle server, which would then tunnel to your database. This is beyond my knowledge so I couldn't give you a concrete sample on how to do it, but I'm fairly certain you would need this middleman.

My suggestion is to work with the tools you already have and change your approach. Instead of connecting from Apps Script to the database, you can connect with something that already works and then send the data to an Apps Script webhook that can process it.

Since you can already connect to the database with Python, you could use it as a mediator by getting the data with Python, then set up a [Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) with Apps Script. A `doPost()` function can act as a webhook, so you can send the data with Python in JSON format as a POST, then receive it on Apps Script. You still need a Python script as a middleman, but it's much easier than setting up an SSH tunnel.

Check out the docs on Web Apps to see if this works for you:

- [Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web)