# Can't establish connection to local Microsoft SQL Server with Googls Apps Script and JDBC

Tags: sql-server, google-apps-script, jdbc

I'm trying to make a connection to a local MS-SQL Server using Google Apps Script with JDBC, but I got following error message "Exception: Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password."

My script has the following code:

```
function getConnection() 
{
    let HostName = "192.XX.0.XX";
    let DatabaseName = "my_base";
    let Username = "william";
    let Password = "XXXXXXXX";
    let Port = "7990";
    let url = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+HostName+":"+Port+"/"+DatabaseName;
    let connection = Jdbc.getConnection(url, Username, Password);
    Logger.log(connection);
    connection.close();
}
```

I would like to connect Google Apps Script to a local database in MS-SQL Server using JDBC.

Comment: sql server are usually blocked from the wide world, if you use the sql server on another maschine in the lan, you must search how to allow it

Comment: Aside... 192.168.*.* addresses are non-routable addresses, they won't be available for connections outside of your own network. You'll need to talk to your network administrators about setting up a port mapping on a NAT firewall/router somewhere.

Comment: Related question: [Google Apps Script - Connect to MySQL DB with ssh](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75795251/1330560)